# Where does "add team member" button on opportunity team render

Tags: opportunity-teams

I'm trying to decipher where each of three similar buttons on opportunity teams is used, specifically:

- Add -> classic : opens add multiple team member interface
- Add team member -> ???
- Add opportunity team members -> lightning : opens add multiple team member interface

I have all three set to visible, but cannot find Add team member anywhere on the page layout in classic or lightning.

I'm hoping to find an option to add a single team member, as it does not appear possible to add custom fields on opp teams to the add-multiple interface in classic or lightning.

Screenshot below

**button config**

[image: button config]

**classic**

[image: classic]

**lightning**

[image: lightning]

Comment: brief update : logged a case and a week in salesforce support has not figured out where the button is used.

Comment: Made it to tier 3...

Comment: got an update today : tier 3 is still looking for documentation.  apparently there is a button looking for a home

Comment: latest update : I just received an update from them is that they are reaching for an help to our R & D (Research and development) team for further update, for now they are working with the notes needed for escalating to our R & D team an soon provide us an update.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The official answer is....nobody knows.  Per my case rep, it's "working as designed" and nobody has any additional information.